# Failed to add RXjava dependency from pom file in intellij

Tags: maven, rx-java

I tried to open a maven project with Intellij. The project was originally created on eclipse and worked fine.
However I receive an error

> Dependency 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19' not found

(I get the same error if I try to start a new project in Intellij with the rxjava dependency)
Here is my dependencies section in the POM file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the entire POM file here? I suspect IntelliJ idea is not correctly locating the online maven sources.

Try deleting the maven home and reopen the project. IntelliJ will be forced to download all dependencies.

Comment: @RajanPrasad 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.rx</groupId>
 <artifactId>rx-play</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
   <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.19</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: @RajanPrasad the error is on line of the version, even though the version exists+it worked in eclipse+ It gives the same error with other versions

Answer (score 0):

running

```
mvn clean install
```

from command line, solved the issue